# Adding an UIImageView and a Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added an `imageview`, and i am trying to add an button over it. How to do it.

```
self.imgview = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"]];
[self.imgview addSubView:button];

[self.view addSubView:imgView];
```

What i get is the `f.png` Image,  i dont see the button that i added over it. How could i resolve this ?

I have no idea what is wrong and i have been stuck in this problem for hours. I need your help

Comment: add them both to another view.

Comment: Do you see the button if you only add it to self.view without adding imgView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the views' frames:

```
self.imgview = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"]];
self.button =  [[UIButton alloc] init];

[imgview setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];  

[self.view addSubView:imgView];
[self.view addSubView:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.imgview = [UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"]];
[self.view addSubView:imgView];
[self.view addSubView:button];
```

Just add them both to the view, adding the button after the image so that it composes on top of the image. Assuming their frame's x,y coordinates also match up.

Comment: Well, i tried doing this using the interface builder, but i end up having the same problem. Help ?

Comment: I don't think this is really the problem. In **shajem** code the button is a subview of the image view, so it can't be covered by the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bringSubviewToFront method